# how can I change the programs icon

Tags: java, icons

I tried looking up multiple tutorials on how to change the programs icon in java but none of them seem to work. I was also wondering what kind of image can it be .ico or .png eg and what size it had to be

Comment: Linux uses .png for file icons, unlike Windows where .ico is used.

Comment: What format should I use if I'm going to make cross-compatible programs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're using a `JFrame`, then you want `setIconImage(java.awt.Image)`:

```
File/InputStream/URL x = ...
Image icon = ImageIO.read(x);
frame.setIconImage(icon);
```

The image file format is irrelevant as long as ImageIO can read it (JPEG, GIF, PNG, TIFF, even BMP if really really necessary).

An example:

```
import java.net.URL;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Custom Icon");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);

        // something off the Google Images front page
        final URL url = new URL("http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQbcDkaRcrbsYFUcE6Q7n56_LJr-r4mDqYTOTtPKG9J0MzZcV6V");
        frame.setIconImage(ImageIO.read(url));

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**Edit: How to get a URL to your icon**

You should place your image files (icons, etc) along with your source code, maybe into its own sub folder in your `src` folder and access them as "resource". Check out [How to use Icons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) from the Java Tutorial for how to get a `URL` object to a resource.

Comment: I'd recommend `setIconImages(icons)` to set multiple icons instead.  At least in Win7, ideally you want a 16x16 icon for the window title bar, and a 32x32 icon for the task bar.  If you just set a 16x16 icon, the task bar icon will look bad.  I imagine other OSes might require different icon sizes as well.

Comment: @Matthewj You cannot pass a `String` to `ImageIO.read()`, it must be a `InputStream`, `URL` or `File` object. I added a full example to my answers above -- I updated my answer to show how to get a URL to an image resource.

Comment: @Matthewj Also, you must call `setImageIcon()/setImageIcons()` on an *instance* of JFrame, these aren't static methods.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Philipp made it quite clear, that `x` has to be a `File`, `InputStream` or `URL`, not a `String` as it seems you tried.

Now, you also need to have a `Frame` or `JFrame` to have an icon!

I presume this is in your `main` method.
To create a frame try

```
JFrame frame=new JFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

followed by @Philipp's code.

--

It just occured to me you might mean the icon of the program shortcut in your operating system. This isn't done in Java but in your operating system. unless you use Java Web start